# Is there a better structure for this else if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to construct an `if else` statement here and am getting a little confused with the `return` values and the `boolean` result that we get from the condition.

Is it possible to have two statements `return true` in this case or will it exit after the first block?

Is there a better way to write this? (maybe using a `switch`?)

This code works with withdrawals of a checking account. I want it to conform to the following rules:

- Return false if the amount to be withdrawn is == or < 0.
- Return true if amount to be withdrawn > 0.
- Check and return true if amount to be withdrawn > balance. (but only one time,  since I want to allow an account to become overdrawn only once.)

```
public boolean withdraw(double amount) {

//amount = amount of money asked to be withdrawn

    if (amount > balance) {
        setBalance(balance - amount - overdraftFee);
        return true;
    } else if (amount == 0) {
        System.out.println("Withdrawal amount cannot be $0.00!");
        return false;
    } else if (amount < 0) {
        System.out.println("Withdrawal amount cannot be a negative amount!");
        return false;
    } else {
        setBalance(balance - amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are could be multiple ways to write it in more concise way, but I'd do it like this:

```
public boolean withdraw(double amount) {
    if (amount <= 0.0) {
        System.out.println("Withdrawal amount should be positive!");
        return false;
    }

    double fee = (amount > balance) ? overdraftFee : 0.0;
    setBalance(balance - amount - fee);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So the second block here is saying: if the amount is greater than the balance, then keep the overdraft fee what it is and perform the operation below.  But if it is not greater than the balance, change overdraftFee to 0, and then perform operation?

Comment: @KevinOcampo it doesn't change `overdraftFee`, but assigns different value to another variable `fee`

Answer (score 3):

The method will stop the **first** time it hits a `return`. A side effect of this is that you don't need to use `else` blocks if it will have returned in the `if` block (as everything after that block will only get run if the condition was `false`).

More importantly, `double` is not a good choice to use for currency amounts in Java, and will cause rounding errors in your code (I'll explain more after the code block). The better option is `BigDecimal`.

Another way to write it would be:

```
public boolean withdraw(BigDecimal amount) {

    if (BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(amount)) {
        System.out.println("Withdrawal amount cannot be $0.00!");
        return false;
    }

    if (BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(amount) < 0) {
        System.out.println("Withdrawal amount cannot be a negative amount!");
        return false;
    }

    BigDecimal feeToCharge = (this.balance.compareTo(amount) < 0) ? this.overdraftFee : BigDecimal.ZERO;

    setBalance(this.balance.minus(amount).minus(feeToCharge));
    return true;

}
```

The reason to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double` for currency is that due to the way a double is represented internally, not all decimal numbers can be accurately stored. This leads to rounding errors, which is important for currency. For example, the following test fails:

```
    @Test
    public void testDoubleSubtraction() {
        assertThat(0.3D - 0.1D, is(0.2D));
    }
```

with the error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <0.2>
     but: was <0.19999999999999998>
```

Comment: plus-one for BigDecimal

Answer (score -5):

You can use Switch Case

```
switch (amount) {
  case (0):
   //your code here
   break;
  case (0>):
   //your code here
   break;
}
```